# Has the culture of acceptable questions on SE changed over time?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, asking-questions

I am relatively new to SE, but I have noticed something quite peculiar. I often am reading lots of old questions (years old) and encounter many that are very short, show very little self-attempt, and are probably just homework questions, yet, they have far more upvotes than I would expect. When I see these types of questions that are asked in the past year or so, they are usually downvoted very quickly, or have few to no upvotes.

I am not talking about massively upvoted questions, just everyday questions such as these: [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1497825/why-cant-pp-p-1p-1-n2-be-a-square), [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72844/is-the-pointwise-maximum-of-two-riemann-integrable-functions-riemann-integrable), [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728620/is-fx-sin1-x-x-ne0-f0-0-riemann-integrable-on-0-1), and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61054/if-a-frac1b-b-frac1c-c-frac1a-for-distinct-a-b-c-how-to-find-the-v).

It seems as though the culture of acceptable questions on SE has dramatically changed over time, and I am wondering why? Perhaps when the SE was newer, users were more likely to upvote because there were far fewer questions?

My question is similar to [this one](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29471/historical-lock-for-preserving-old-low-quality-questions), however, it was posted 3 years ago and it seems this phenomenon has increased greatly since.

Comment: (1) the culture has probably changed over time, but also (2) there are questions asked today which are not acceptable, but which nevertheless are not closed/deleted, as there are not enough eyes to deal with *every* question asked---this has always been true, thus there are questions asked ages ago, which weren't appropriate at the time of asking, but which have managed to survive.

Comment: Another aspect of time is that upvotes can accumulate, so seeing older Questions with "tons of upvotes" may happen when users find that a problem they have was already asked and answered.  I don't think it is bad if that's how it happens.  The timeline of a Question might reveal how quickly votes accumulated.

Comment: Requirement for context was definitely a thing even a decade ago, but there was less pressure then to be obeying the *letter* of the law.

Comment: might be interesting to see top scored Qs on the site [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=MostVotes&edited=true)

Comment: I don't have solid evidence for this, but i have the impression that COVID lock downs left lots of students with severely reduced access to teachers, and dealing with the resulting flood affected the population and the culture here.

Comment: Searching meta for `eoqs` should return some relevant hits.

Comment: Some of this drift is natural and a product of MSE's success - there are fewer new questions that can get away without as much motivation/context/etc in the post after 10 years of this site's existence because *they've already been posted*.

Comment: *It seems as though the culture of acceptable questions on SE has dramatically changed over time, and I am wondering why?* Changing needs of the site: the growth in traffic and accumulated content generate a need to regulate what comes in afterwards.  Honestly it would be really strange for a site like this one to function essentially the same way after a decade...

Comment: How many upvotes in a ton?

Comment: Seriously though, when an old question pops up I find myself wishing I were there back in 2011. Answers regularly got 50 upvotes back then, and they weren't anything special!

Comment: @Mike 10 years from now, many recent questions will have 50+ upvotes.

Comment: Some of the old questions were dealing with elementary topics for the first time. Now such questions are inevitably duplicates one way or another and tend to be marked as such. I think the culture has changed, and partly because that elementary part of the question spectrum is pretty saturated.

Comment: Another reason is that there has broadly been a move to abstract questions and to dealing with the mathematical content, rather than (as some of us did more in the past) trying to help people negotiate their personal mental blocks with the material.

Comment: This seems to be only tangential to the main question, but since you mentioned score/votes: [Has the upvoting really gone down?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27004), [Statistics on upvoting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6668), [Is voting on questions getting harsher?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22010), etc. In [this graph](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1416686/various-types-of-votes-per-month?Date2=2023-12-31#graph) you can see how the *total* number of upvotes evolved over time.

Comment: I see from this thread that "prohibiting answers in comments" has not made its way into the enforced quality standards yet. /s

Comment: I occasionally come here to ask quick questions when I can't locate an expert colleague or don't want to bother them with an easy problem. The "quality" police (who usually have nothing mathematically interesting to add) have been noticeably more annoying in recent years. They even downvote and vote to close. It's just completely rude.

Comment: This is annoying, I am rarely here, usually in stack overflow as a CS researcher, but sometimes I have math related questions and a subsets of those times I can't find the answer and I don't have a mathematician at hand. Today I decided to see if I could get help with such a question here. Someone downvoted it and left no comment either. Usually when I downvote someone on stackoverflow I comment explaining why, particularly if he is an occasional user.

Comment: I think more questions get zapped nowadays under the guise of 'presumed no effort'. Some get deleted without any explanation. There is an admirable effort to accumulate standard answers to standard questions, but I have difficulty locating it.

Comment: I have experienced a much higher level of impatience with beginners recently. I'm shedding reputation at such a rate this might be my last comment.

Comment: This was the best! I was discussing the clarity problems of my question with someone clearly more expert then me and understood where the problem lies. Edit the post with examples and when I am done, the question was already closed... Who closes a question while there is already a ongoing clarification process? Jesus

Comment: I have also observed that the site has taken a more formal and bureaucratic and less friendly atmosphere over the years. It has definitely dampened my interest here. I generally don't engage with low quality questions anyways, but the general air of hostility makes the place un-fun. It feels like a bad homeowners association, with self-appointed authorities going around harassing everyone for minor infractions.

Comment: I'm new here and I visited the site not so often, but I have a long experience of other sites of mathematics. My impression here is that people often downvote and close question hastily, without thinking about what they are doing. And this not only wrong, but also rude.